# how to create a foreign key in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to link the `MgrId` in `ManagerProject` to `EmpId` in the `Employee` table ?
This is wat I tried :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(EmpId varchar2(5), 
                       EmpName varchar2(25), 
                       DeptId varchar2(3),
                       Salary Number(8),
Constraint PK_addn primary key (EmpId, DeptId),
Constraint fk_Department foreign key (DeptId) references Department (DeptId));
```

But the second table failed to be created :

```
CREATE TABLE ManagerProject(ProjId varchar2(4),
                            MgrId varchar2(5),
                            StartDate Date,
                            EndDate Date,
Constraint fk_managerproject foreign key (MgrId) references Employee (EmpId),
Constraint PK_Managerproject Primary key(ProjId, MgrId, StartDate));
```

It displays

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: it diaplays ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list when i try to create the ManagerProject Table, Somone Please help

Comment: Why is the primary key on table `employee` a composite key, on two columns `(empid, deptid)`? It should be on only one column, `empid` - unless your business is really strange and unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are trying to create a FK referencing a column on which there is no Unique or Primary Key constraint.

Assuming that you don't want to add the column `DeptId` to `ManagerProject`, you need to add a unique key on `employee`:

```
alter table Employee add constraint empId_UK unique ( empId)
```

But this strongly depends on what your schema should be.

If you want to add the column `DeptId` to `ManagerProject`, you will need to edit your FK to both use `EmpId` and `DeptId` in referencing `employee`.

Comment: MgrId is supposed to be a promary key in the ManagerProject table and is should reference to EmpId in the Employee table;    DeptId References to another Table called Department. Department Relation
 CREATE TABLE Department 
 (DeptId varchar2(3) primary key, 
 DeptName varchar2(30) Unique NOT NULL);

Comment: If you want to create a FK to reference a column in a table, you need to ensure that values in the referenced columns are unique. I beieve you should better understand the structure of your schema before starting to create tables.